# Drawing with UIKit and preload it

Tags: objective-c, ios5, drawrect

I am drawing a graph with UIKIT and I want to show before it is finished a preloader (spinning circle)

Another solution should be before start drawing set the alpha of my view to 0.0 and when it's done fade it to 1.0.

Someone did this before and/or know how to do this?

Comment: I tried apple docs, google, stackoverflow. I did some experiments with the drawrect-method but didn't have the feeling that is's do-able in one thread.
Drawing an animated spinner is not the problem. The problem is that I don't know when to push and pop it. Sorry for being such a n00b!

Comment: It is not about beeing a noob, but it about the kind of question to be discussed here. "Give me the code" is not the way it works, but "here is my code, here is my issue, please help." If you need a pointer, maybe https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html is useful.  Especially, have a look to the presented examples.

Comment: I don't think the code is the problem. I am curious about the approach to solve the problem. And more the combination with preloading and drawrect is interesting for me.

Answer (score 1):

If using UIKit, you could draw the path, fill and stroke, then draw another path. This is resource-intensive as you will be calling `drawRect:` often.

The other way is to create animation. I'll let someone else as I have no experience in creating animation in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an activity indicator to the view, send the view `setNeedsDisplay` and remove the activity indicator at the end of the `drawRect:`, but I doubt you will see the activity indicator at all. Activity indicators are only useful when you are performing some lengthy operations, taking at least several seconds to complete. If drawing the graph is that long, you should either optimize it or consider drawing it on a secondary thread into a `CGImage`. In the latter case, I'm afraid, you restrict yourself to Core Graphics.